# Checking across multiple tables in mySQL

Tags: mysql

## Question:

I am fairly new to mySQL and I don't even know where to begin with this. I want to know how to write a simple function which returns true or false based on values which are spread out across many tables.

## Details:

Here are the relevant parts of my tables (all engines are `innodb`). As you read on, you will see that the database is just storing users, groups, files, and the permissions for those files for those users/groups.

**USER table**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USER
(
   ID                 INT NOT NULL auto_increment,

   PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)
```

**GROUP table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GROUP
(
   ID           INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

   PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)
```

**GROUP MEMBERSHIP table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GROUPMEMBERSHIP
(
   ID           INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   USERID       INT NOT NULL,
   GROUPID      INT NOT NULL,

   UNIQUE ( USERID, GROUPID ),
   PRIMARY KEY(ID),
   FOREIGN KEY (USERID) REFERENCES USER(ID),
   FOREIGN KEY (GROUPID) REFERENCES GROUP(ID)
)
```

**FILE table:** (R, W, X, is for `other`)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FILE
(
   ID                 INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   READ               BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
   WRITE              BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
   EXECUTE            BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,

   PRIMARY KEY(ID)
)
```

**FILE USER PERMISSIONS table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FILEUSERPERMISSIONS
(
   ID           INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   FILEID       INT NOT NULL,
   USERID       INT NOT NULL,
   READ         BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
   WRITE        BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
   EXECUTE      BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,

   UNIQUE (FILEID, USERID),
   PRIMARY KEY(ID),
   FOREIGN KEY (FILEID) REFERENCES FILE(ID),
   FOREIGN KEY (USERID) REFERENCES USER(ID)
)
```

**FILE GROUP PERMISSIONS table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FILEGROUPPERMISSIONS
(
   ID           INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   FILEID       INT NOT NULL,
   GROUPID      INT NOT NULL,
   READ         BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
   WRITE        BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
   EXECUTE      BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,

   UNIQUE (FILEID, GROUPID),
   PRIMARY KEY(ID),
   FOREIGN KEY (FILEID) REFERENCES FILE(ID),
   FOREIGN KEY (GROUPID) REFERENCES GROUP(ID)
)
```

**hasPermission function:**

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS hasPermission$$
CREATE FUNCTION hasPermission(fileID INT, userID INT)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
BEGIN
   ???
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

How would I go about, or at least where do I start writing the `hasPermission` function such that when queried like so:

```
SELECT hasPermission( 123, 456)
```

It carries out the below:

1. Checks to see if file 123 is readable by `other`
2. Checks to see if user 456 has read permissions on file 123
3. Checks to see if user 456 is in some group that has read permissions on file 123

The first one is <del>pretty trivial</del> the most trivial of the three. The second one has me stumped. The third one presents a conceptual barrier for me. In addition to all this, I obviously have to check to see if the user and/or the file exists.

Please be kind as I am a newbie wrt MySQL.

Thank you in advanced

Comment: If only all newcomers to MySQL would write questions like this.  +1

Comment: It's no answer, but I would consider to switch to PostgreSQL, if you want a "clean" DB. MySQL can be really annoying for advanced stuff. I switched and I'd never go back.

Comment: @DavidHalter I actually "learned" PostgreSQL a while back but I forgot it all. Now I have started with MySQL... I really hope you're wrong =P

Comment: @puk: hehe, It's just a question what you want: mysql is quick and dirty, postgres is clean and the unix way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check the right for a file. I would probably do it like this:

```
SELECT
    (
        CASE WHEN EXISTS
            (
                SELECT
                    NULL
                FROM
                    FILE
                WHERE EXISTS
                    (
                        SELECT
                            NULL
                        FROM
                            USER
                            JOIN GROUPMEMBERSHIP
                                ON GROUPMEMBERSHIP.USERID=USER.ID
                            JOIN FILEUSERPERMISSIONS
                                ON FILEUSERPERMISSIONS.USERID=GROUPMEMBERSHIP.USERID
                            JOIN FILEGROUPPERMISSIONS
                                ON FILEGROUPPERMISSIONS.GROUPID=GROUPMEMBERSHIP.GROUPID
                        WHERE 
                            FILEUSERPERMISSIONS.FILEID=FILE.ID
                            AND FILEGROUPPERMISSIONS.FILEID=FILE.ID
                            AND FILEUSERPERMISSIONS.READ=FILE.READ
                            AND FILEGROUPPERMISSIONS.READ=FILE.READ
                            AND USER.ID=userID
                    )
                WHERE
                    FILE.READ=1
                    AND FILE.ID=fileID
            )
        THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
        ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
        END
    ) AS hasRights
```

But if you really want to value of your function. I would suggest using a table function and just supply the `userid`. So that you can get all the files that the user has access to. This will look something like this:

```
SELECT
    ID
FROM
    FILE
WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            NULL
        FROM
            USER
            JOIN GROUPMEMBERSHIP
                ON GROUPMEMBERSHIP.USERID=USER.ID
            JOIN FILEUSERPERMISSIONS
                ON FILEUSERPERMISSIONS.USERID=GROUPMEMBERSHIP.USERID
            JOIN FILEGROUPPERMISSIONS
                ON FILEGROUPPERMISSIONS.GROUPID=GROUPMEMBERSHIP.GROUPID
        WHERE 
            FILEUSERPERMISSIONS.FILEID=FILE.ID
            AND FILEGROUPPERMISSIONS.FILEID=FILE.ID
            AND FILEUSERPERMISSIONS.READ=FILE.READ
            AND FILEGROUPPERMISSIONS.READ=FILE.READ
            AND USER.ID=userID
    )
WHERE
    FILE.READ=1
```

And by the way. The question was dam good. This should be an example of how to ask a question

Comment: Thank you for the response, and the praise. However, to be completely honest, it is not my first question.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I will select one of these two as an answer as soon as I manage to implement both and test which is better. Cheers.

Comment: Looking at your second suggestion, there is a great deal I don't understand: what's `WHERE EXISTS`? What's `SELECT NULL`? What happens in `JOIN` if tables have columns with the same name (ie. `CREATION_DATE`)? Why did you `AND` all the conditions together, should some of them not be `OR`? Why is there a second `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 2):

1. **Check to see if file 123 is readable by `other`**

   You said this is pretty trivial, but for completeness:

   ```
   SELECT READ
   FROM FILE
   WHERE ID = 123;
   ```
2. **Check to see if user 456 has read permissions on file 123**

   You can do this with a similar lookup in the `FILEUSERPERMISSIONS` table:

   ```
   SELECT READ
   FROM FILEUSERPERMISSIONS
   WHERE FILEID = 123 AND USERID = 456;
   ```
3. **Check to see if user 456 is in some group that has read permissions on file 123**

   To accomplish this, you need to [JOIN](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sql+join) the `GROUP MEMBERSHIP` and `FILE GROUP PERMISSIONS` tables:

   ```
   SELECT READ
   FROM FILEGROUPPERMISSIONS JOIN GROUPMEMBERSHIP USING (GROUPID)
   WHERE FILEID = 123 AND USERID = 456;
   ```

---

To combine these together, you could do:

```
SELECT
   (SELECT READ FROM FILE WHERE ID = 123)
OR (SELECT READ FROM FILEUSERPERMISSIONS WHERE FILEID = 123 AND USERID = 456)
OR (SELECT READ FROM FILEGROUPPERMISSIONS JOIN GROUPMEMBERSHIP USING (GROUPID)
    WHERE FILEID = 123 AND USERID = 456);
```

Comment: How would I `OR` those three together? Would I need to `declare` variables then do a `SELECT READ INTO`, and then use an if statement to return true or false? Thanks

Comment: There are many different ways... you could construct a single `SELECT` query that combines each of these values with the [`OR` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/logical-operators.html); you could use an [`IF` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if-statement.html) that places such an operator between separate queries; you could nest the queries within their own `IF` statements; or yes, like you suggest, you could [`SELECT ... INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html) variables and do the above on those.

Comment: @puk: See above for one suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. Wonderfully explained.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I will select one of these two as an answer as soon as I manage to implement both and test which is better. Cheers.

Comment: still restructuring my entire DB (have to add views, then users, then test this out) hence why i haven't selected an answer here. Am going as fast as I can =)

Comment: I had a quick question (I am willing to post it as a brand new one if you like) but what if my sub-query calls the same table again, ie `CREATE VIEW x AS SELECT * FROM y WHERE (SELECT a FROM z JOIN y ON z.y_id = y.id where y.b = b)`. I basically want to know what the scope of `b` is here. Is there any way to reference back to it on the outside?

Comment: @puk: Your query doesn't make a great deal of sense... `WHERE (SELECT a ...)`?  Not sure what you're trying to achieve.  Perhaps best as a new question, if nothing else because the additional space for explanation?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ultimately chose Arion's answer as I used his suggestion of "valuing my function" by instead returning a table of all files.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness I am also posting my solution to how I solved this problem. My initial motivation was to create a function to see if one linux user (ie. `user1`) has access to another linux user's (ie. `user2`) home folder (ie. whether `user1` has read permissions on `/home/user2`). I would then use this function when constructing a `VIEW` for each mysql user by using the `user()` function (assuming the mysql usernames and linux usernames are one to one). Thanks to Arion's suggestion, I now, instead, am creating a view using joins instead.

Note, for the purposes of this example, the home *folder* is stored in the `FILE` table.

**USER_VIEW view:**

```
CREATE VIEW USER_VIEW
AS
SELECT 
   U.ID
FROM 
   USERS AS U
   LEFT JOIN FILES AS F
      ON U.ID = F.USER_ID
   LEFT JOIN FILE_USER_PERMISSIONS AS P
      ON F.ID = P.FILE_ID
   LEFT JOIN USERS AS S
      ON P.USER_ID = S.ID
WHERE
(
   U.USERNAME = SUBSTR( USER(), 1, POSITION( '@' IN USER() ) - 1 )
)
OR
(
   F.R = TRUE
)
OR
(
   U.HOME = F.PATH AND P.R = TRUE AND S.USERNAME = SUBSTR( USER(), 1, POSITION( '@' IN USER() ) - 1 )
)
UNION
SELECT 
   U.ID
FROM 
   USERS AS U
   LEFT JOIN FILES AS F
      ON U.ID = F.USER_ID
   LEFT JOIN FILE_GROUP_PERMISSIONS AS P
      ON F.ID = P.FILE_ID
   LEFT JOIN GROUP_MEMBERSHIP AS G
      ON P.GROUP_ID = G.ID
   LEFT JOIN USERS AS S
      ON G.USER_ID = S.ID
WHERE
(
   U.HOME = F.PATH AND P.R = TRUE AND S.USERNAME = SUBSTR( USER(), 1, POSITION( '@' IN USER() ) - 1 )
)
```

**EDIT:** I believe instead of issuing a command like

```
CREATE VIEW USER_VIEW
AS
SELECT 
   U.ID
FROM 
    ...
```

I can just do

```
CREATE VIEW USER_VIEW
AS
SELECT 
   U.*
FROM 
    ...
```

Which comes in handy if you want to copy 10+ columns